# SAS handling empty space

Tags: string, sas

I am trying to write a small SAS script that validates answers that are stored in a mySQL database.  There is the possibility that a variable can have an blank space ie " ".  My SAS code can't/won't pick it up anything that is just a blank so my error handling is wrong.

For example, I have a variable "Able to stand" that can be either Yes or No.  There is a chance that nothing was filled out and so in the database it is represented as " " (not a null, and its a nvarchar(1)).  In my code I have tried multiple ways to get a blank space but all of them skip over it:

```
*Doesn't work;
if ABLE_TO_STAND = ' ' then do;
err_cat = 1000;
err_desc = cat( "ABLE_TO_STAND: Missing", " ");
err_count = err_count + 1;
output;
end; 

*Does work;
if ABLE_TO_STAND not in ('Y','N') then do;
err_cat = 1001;
err_desc = cat( "ABLE_TO_STAND: Invalid", " ");
err_count = err_count +1;
output;
end;
```

The second check works just fine, but the first is never triggered (My data has a few instances where it should show up).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you need to pass the "Yes" , "NO" variable through a regex that will trim extra spaces.. something like this::  temp = Able_to_stand('s/\s+/ /');

Comment: Is this data step directly accessing the mySQL database?  Or is this down the line somewhere?  I would expect the first to work in SAS, though it may or may not match your expectation.  SAS defines null in a character field as ' ' (or any number of purely blank spaces), so it's possible it's passing the ' ' back to mySQL as 'null' if you're doing this in a direct connection.  In SAS you wouldn't be able to differentiate between true `NULL` and `' '` though - you'd have to use some other value to define non-null blank space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run the following and it works fine in sas 9.3.  why do you say it doesn't work?

```
 data test;                                                                                                                             
 ABLE_TO_STAND = ' ';                                                                                                                  
 err_count = 0;                                                                                                                        
 if ABLE_TO_STAND = ' ' then do;                                                                                                    
 err_cat = 1000;                                                                                                                         
 err_desc = cat( "ABLE_TO_STAND: Missing", ABLE_TO_STAND);                                                                               
 err_count = err_count + 1;                                                                                                              
 output;                                                                                                                                 
 end;                                                                                                                                    
 run;
```

Comment: I've tried running it again as is from my home machine and it does work.  I've looked into it quite a bit more and it seems that somewhere between transferring the SAS script from a windows machine to linux to execute it and then transferring it back the blank spaces were appended with a % which wouldn't show up in SAS.  Thanks everyone for your pointers as it helped me track down the general error I was getting.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `MISSING` function:

```
if MISSING(ABLE_TO_STAND) then do;
```

Comment: This would be better with some explanation as to why it works.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it would work based on the question, so perhaps should have been a comment instead of an answer.